# Dealing with change requests while facing lots of dependencies

Tags: requirements, stakeholders, dependencies

We have a system with multiple stakeholders and surrounding systems influencing it.

It might be possible to draw a dependency diagram but this would be not very easy to interpret because of the complexity.

The several stakeholders raise new requirements during the definition phase. Due to the systems' high interdependency, it's hard to identify consequences with respect to existing dependencies.

How to manage this topic?

I have a sense that there should be something from the requirements management domain or the stakeholder management domain to deal with this task but I don't understand it...

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't have a PM problem at all, but rather an overly complicated and overly coupled code base.

Comment: Actually it's more like an embedded system. Nevertheless, any suggestions?

Comment: You and your team should split up the work until you get down to something you can understand / estimate etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our ERP system functions as a key interlocking dependency (a.k.a. nightmare) for a ton of difference custom systems. The way we managed this to have an "architectural committee" where three top technical people act as a change-control board for changes to an identified "core" system. They were charged with identifying risks and controlling changed but ***also*** with trying to find ways to minimize interoperability problems.

Over the years, they have built "pre-approved" or "pre-designed" ways to use the ERP data (APIs, automated extracts, etc.) that other dev teams have used for their projects.